# Do open source(or amd's) drivers work well for hd5570 graphics card?

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics

Do open source(or amd's) drivers work well for hd5570? 
Especially on ubuntu 11.10
I don't have it but i want to buy so if anyone could tell me i would be greatful.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a 5770 XFX XXX 1Gb RAM, and in my experience the answer is: no.
After taking a look at the official documentation the answer is still no.

The thing is that the radeon driver package, a.k.a. the open source driver for the ATI vga, offers some support for the oldest cards, for the new ones there are two main option:

- the fglrx package that basically contain proprietary driver but
  packed by the Ubuntu team ( tipically outdated package )
- the, so called, fglrx ccc AMD ATI proprietary closed driver ( that are the
  most updated drivers and probably the right ones for your card )

Downloading and building your own package from the latest driver available from AMD ATI is a pretty easy task http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Main_Page and gives you good performance.

Comment: FGLRX is the same for both cases you mention, Both come with the Catalyst Control Center and both are propietary closed drivers, the only difference is that AMD  one is the latest released while the one in the repositories is not and will not get updated.

Comment: i make a distinction simply because is usual in this case; you are right saying that are both basically the same but the AMD one are the most up to date. Some docs on the internet make the same distinction, if i only say fglrx you can confuse the two.

Comment: Have you tried any of the above proprietary drivers? what's your experience? Thanks!!!

Comment: i have followed the instructions by cchtml.com and all went fine, in other words i always use the proprietary driver downloaded from the official website; i can suggest you to do the same. The other 2 option: the radeon package it's simply not made for modern ATI cards and the fglrx package from the repo is really outdated, so i suggest to not consider these two options because of that.

Comment: You mean that it worked perfectly when you followed the instruction from the specific website right? Sorry for being tiring but i just want to make sure that this card will work perfectly when i buy it...thanks again!

Comment: yes, that's what i meant.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using HD5850, and I'm very satisfied with the open radeon driver that's used by default. You can achieve better performance with the proprietary drivers, but they don't always work well and have problems of their own. I prefer to use the open drivers. They just work and I can expect my VGA performance to increase over time. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using Ubuntu 11.10 and AMD HD6800. Additional drivers didn't work att all, so i find this page -

- http://mrrichard.hubpages.com/hub/2-Ways-to-Install-FGLRX-in-Ubuntu-1110-Oneric - and with this

Option 2: Manually Download/install/Configure the ATI Driver - everything works great.

Here is option 2:

1. Download your driver from AMD's website: http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx
2. Right click on the downloaded file. Go to Properties and allow it to be executed as a program.
3. Now double click the file, let it run in Terminal, and enter you password when and if required.
4. Once done, open up another Terminal and enter the following command: sudo aticonfig --initial
5. Reboot

This method applies to all Ubuntu-based distros (Kubuntu, Linux Mint, Xubuntu etc.), by the way.

Answer (score 1):

I have an Ati 5470 and I use the opensource driver in Ubuntu 11.10, because with the proprietary driver Ubuntu had many problems with this video card (like Unity 3D is screwed up and unusable). With this, Unity 2D works, but it gets hot after some time of use and there is already a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/748080) opened for that.-

I solved it changing the profile of the ati driver, as suggested [here](http://javacolors.blogspot.com/2011/10/ubuntu-1110-ati-radeon-deal.html), and installing [Jupiter](http://cisight.com/install-amd-radeon-hd-6470m-and-solve-overheat-on-ubuntu-1110-oneiric/), which is a battery consumption indicator.

And, on startup, brightness is always low and you have to manually get it normal with the brightness function button on the keyboard..there is already a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/873191) also for this problem.