# Fan is always on on a Toshiba L300, is this normal?

Tags: 11.10, power-management

I've installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my Toshiba l300 and I have a problem with the fan which works constantly and this is unusual...Have you got the solution?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with Ati open-source driver.
I solved it as described in this question..

[Do open source(or amd's) drivers work well for hd5570 graphics card?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81340/do-open-sourceor-amds-drivers-work-well-for-hd5570-graphics-card/82585#82585)