# ATI 5770 HD - its fan runs all time - how can I resolve this?

Tags: 11.10, drivers, ati

I have another problem with my HD 5770 ATI card.

It's fan all the time runs with the same speed (i think it's about 60% cause i dont know how to measure it on Ubuntu).

I have installed the drivers following this method

- http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Natty_Installation_Guide

Even if i left my computer for three hours alone without any aplication runing, or watching video - every time it has the same speed.

I have dual boot with Windows 7 and there my graphic card fan is slow when i dont use PC and runs quicker if i start videos or games.

How to solve this problem?

I read that i can set fan speed to custom value, for example 30%, but how to make it to control automaticaly by the drivers. Thanks. (Sorry for my english, im not from english speaking country and it's hard for me to speak it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have installed the right drivers but using a method that is not for your Ubuntu version.

For more information on how to install, remove and revert drivers please follow the link to this question

- [Is my ATI graphics card supported in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74171/is-my-ati-graphics-card-supported-in-ubuntu)

If you have installed the proprietary drivers and there is a problem with the fan speed you need to report that to AMD as a bug in the drivers.

As a workaround for that you might want to set a lower power state using the `aticonfig` tool. Set it on a console using this command:

```
aticonfig --set-powerstate=1
```

To find out which powerstates your Radeon supports try:

```
aticonfig --lsp
```

Comment: Can you describe for me what is proprietary AMD driver? i use this drivers and installed them though creating deb packages in wiki tutorial - http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx?type=2.4.1&product=2.4.1.3.42&lang=English - sry, i use ubuntu for 2 or 3 days

Comment: Yes, i use this tutorial - http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Natty_Installation_Guide - Gonna check your post and then report if it helps, thanks

Comment: The intallation guide you followed is for Natty. Why not the 11.10 one? Im not sure how different the packages created woul be but that might be the cause for your issue

Comment: It's all because i am lame in Ubuntu :)

Comment: Great, I will ask a moderator to purge these comments. Regards.

Comment: @MarcoCeppi can we purge this please?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [this answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81340/do-open-sourceor-amds-drivers-work-well-for-hd5570-graphics-card/82585#82585), solving the problem changing the profile of the open source ati driver that you are using and installing Jupiter, which is an applet to control the performance of your video card, battery consumption, etc. There is also a bug for this problem, you can find it in the answer above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, im gonna to check this solution when i come home from work. But i think it wont work cause i use drivers from AMD website, and installed them though creating deb packages.

Comment: I tried the proprietary drivers and there were some problems with Unity (crashes, etc.), but the fan problem was gone. So I think that maybe you haven't installed them correctly and that you are still using the opensource one. If so, the proposed solution should work then.

Comment: Ooops, maybe you are right :)